# How to find what git commit a given tf-nightly (tensorflow nightly build) is coming from?

Tags: tensorflow

You can install the nightly build via:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

How to figure out what code commit this is coming from? I have looked int he tags from the github tensorflow branch and do not see any corresponding to the `tf.__version__` that is showing in the REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__git_version__, tf.__version__)"
```

printed the following in my experiment:

```
v1.12.1-25814-g2e81bc66c5 2.2.0-dev20200225
```

The SHA of the commit is the string at the end, after `-g`. In this case it was `2e81bc66c5`.

The accepted answer did not work for me with `tf_nightly-2.2.0.dev20200225`. All I got was `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'VERSION'` and `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GIT_VERSION'`

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)"
```

From the tensorflow new issue template:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?template=00-bug-performance-issue.md